# KineticJS: Clone Duplicates Classes Custom Events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, clone, kineticjs

I create some custom events in the constructor of a KineticJS class

```
    this.on('mouseover', this.mouseOver);
    this.on('mouseout', this.mouseOut);
    this.on('dblclick', this.dblclick);
```

When I clone this class I end up having these event listeners duplicated.

```
    var copy = this.clone();
    this.parent.add(copy);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(copy);
```

You can see the duplication if you drill down into the event listeners on my Entity class.

```
eventListeners: Object
  dblclick: Array[2]
  mouseout: Array[2]
  mouseover: Array[2]
```

The full example is on the following jsFiddle, double click on the circle to have a copy made.
http://jsfiddle.net/qQEj7/

Am I defining my event listeners incorrectly here? Is there a different way to do this when using KineticJS?

Comment: I wanted to note that I did try

    **this.off('mouseover mouseout dblclick');**

before setting the event listeners with no change to the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange behavior.. I looked at it for a while but couldn't come up with an answer as to why `clone()` was duplicating your event listeners. It looks like because of the way you structured your `Kinetic.Entity`, everytime you `clone()` your entity, it would clone the node like normal, but ALSO add again your defined `eventListeners` (which is undesired).

Maybe this happens because when you `clone()` your Entity node, it clones the eventListeners, but also calls your `_initEntity` function which binds the eventListeners again??

If you call `clone()` on a regular `Kinetic.Shape` the issue does not occur. This tells me it probably has something to do with the way you define your eventListeners in your `Kinetic.Entity` along with how it plays with the `clone()` method.

In your comment above, you mentioned that you tried:

`this.off('mouseover mouseout dblclick');`

Well this worked for me, but it would remove the eventListeners from the original node (that you double clicked). It depends on when you called the line above though:

1. If you copied the node **before** removing the eventListeners, then the new node will still have the original eventListeners + the `clone()` seems to add a set of the eventListeners you defined, thus you will end up with **2** sets of eventListeners which we didn't want.
2. If you copied the node **after** removing the eventListeners, then the original node will lose it's eventListeners, and then the new node will have no eventListeners to start with, but then the `clone()` method adds a set of eventListeners.

In any case, I did find a way that works so hopefully it works for you. I created a new method which adds your events:

```
_bindEvents: function() {
    this.on('mouseover.entity', this.mouseOver);
    this.on('mouseout.entity', this.mouseOut);
    this.on('dblclick.entity', this.dblclick);
},
```

And I call this inside your `_initEntity` function.

Then, for your double click event, you remove your eventListeners by calling `off` on the **copied** node (not **this** - the node your clicked!), that way the original node keeps it's eventListeners, and the new node removes all eventListeners that were copied and duplicated. After remove the eventsListeners from the copied node, you can recall `_bindEvents` to bind the events back in place:

```
dblclick: function () {
    var copy = this.clone();
    copy.off('.entity');
    copy._bindEvents();
    this.parent.add(copy);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(copy);
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/V5AYc/).

**TIP:** Notice that I named your events like this `mouseover.entity`, `mouseout.entity`, `dblclick.entity`. This is because KineticJS allows you to name your events to group them together. Naming those events **`.entity`** allows me to remove them all in one go by calling `.off('.entity')`. This makes things cleaner, more scalable and easier to manage than calling something like `.off('mouseover mouseout dblclick')`. Just think, if you added a new eventListener like `mousedown`, you would also have to edit your `off` function to `.off('mouseover mouseout dblclick mousedown')`, and every other time you add another event!

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked well. I tried doing the .off call right before I set my listeners, which wasn't working. Doing the .off and then rebinding works well. Thanks for the **TIP** as well, that is good to know!